# Convolutional neural network outputting equal probabilities for all labels

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am currently training a CNN on MNIST, and the output probabilities (softmax) are giving [0.1,0.1,...,0.1] as training goes on. The initial values aren't uniform, so I can't figure out if I'm doing something stupid here?

I'm only training for 15 steps, just to see how training progresses; even though that's a low number, I don't think that should result in uniform predictions?

```python
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import imageio

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

# Getting data

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def one_hot_encode(data):
    new_ = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        _ = np.zeros([10],dtype=np.float32)
        _[int(data[i])] = 1.0
        new_.append(np.asarray(_))
    return new_

data = np.asarray(mnist["data"],dtype=np.float32)
labels = np.asarray(mnist["target"],dtype=np.float32)
labels = one_hot_encode(labels)
tr_data,test_data,tr_labels,test_labels = train_test_split(data,labels,test_size = 0.1)
tr_data = np.asarray(tr_data)
tr_data = np.reshape(tr_data,[len(tr_data),28,28,1])
test_data = np.asarray(test_data)
test_data = np.reshape(test_data,[len(test_data),28,28,1])
tr_labels = np.asarray(tr_labels)
test_labels = np.asarray(test_labels)

def get_conv(x,shape):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape,stddev=0.05))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([shape[-1]],stddev=0.05))
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x,weights,[1,1,1,1],padding="SAME")
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv,biases))

def get_pool(x,shape):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=shape,strides=shape,padding="SAME")

def get_fc(x,shape):
    sh = x.get_shape().as_list()
    dim = 1
    for i in sh[1:]:
        dim *= i
    x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,dim])
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape,stddev=0.05))
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,weights) + tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([shape[1]],stddev=0.05)))

#Creating model

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,28,28,1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

conv1_1 = get_conv(x,[3,3,1,128])
conv1_2 = get_conv(conv1_1,[3,3,128,128])
pool1 = get_pool(conv1_2,[1,2,2,1])

conv2_1 = get_conv(pool1,[3,3,128,512])
conv2_2 = get_conv(conv2_1,[3,3,512,512])
pool2 = get_pool(conv2_2,[1,2,2,1])

conv3_1 = get_conv(pool2,[3,3,512,1024])
conv3_2 = get_conv(conv3_1,[3,3,1024,1024])
conv3_3 = get_conv(conv3_2,[3,3,1024,1024])
conv3_4 = get_conv(conv3_3,[3,3,1024,1024])
pool3 = get_pool(conv3_4,[1,3,3,1])

fc1 = get_fc(pool3,[9216,1024])
fc2 = get_fc(fc1,[1024,10])

softmax = tf.nn.softmax(fc2)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=fc2,onehot_labels=y)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(15):
    print(i)
    indices = np.random.randint(len(tr_data),size=[200])
    batch_data = tr_data[indices]
    batch_labels = tr_labels[indices]
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_data,y:batch_labels})
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your `fc2` should not have a ReLU activation - only `softmax`

Comment: could you add the part of your code that actually prints and maybe also a sample of the output?

Comment: Answers take up valuable time for the respondents; if the answer has addressed your question, kindly accept it (upvotes are most welcome, too) - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, including elementary ones. I strongly suggest you first go through the Tensorflow step-by-step tutorials for MNIST, [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) and [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros).

In short, regarding your code:

First, your final layer `fc2` should **not** have a ReLU activation.

Second, the way you build your batches, i.e.

```python
indices = np.random.randint(len(tr_data),size=[200])
```

is by just grabbing random samples in each iteration, which is far from the correct way of doing so...

Third, the data you feed into the network are not normalized in [0, 1], as they should be:

```python
np.max(tr_data[0]) # get the max value of your first training sample
# 255.0
```

---

The third point was initially puzzling for me, too, since in the aforementioned Tensorflow tutorials they don't seem to normalize the data either. But close inspection revealed the reason: if you import the MNIST data through the Tensorflow-provided utility functions (instead of the scikit-learn ones, as you do here), they come already normalized in [0, 1], something that is nowhere hinted at:

```python
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
np.max(mnist.train.images[0])
# 0.99607849
```

This is an admittedly strange design decision - as far as I am aware of, in all other similar cases/tutorials normalizing the input data is an explicit part of the pipeline (see e.g. the [Keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py)), and with good reason (it is something you will be certainly expected to do yourself later, when using your own data).

Comment: Oh, I see. Got it. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: @PianPawakapan you re doing fine ;)