# Getting very bad prediction with KerasRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I used KerasRegressor on a dummy dataset and tried to predict the training values itself. It is giving me an output far from satisfactory. The training data is not random at all. Could anyone help me out?

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

import numpy as ny

X = ny.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]])
Y = ny.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
N = 5

def brain():
    #Create the brain
    br_model=Sequential()
    br_model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
    br_model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
    br_model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal'))

    #Compile the brain
    br_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
    return br_model


estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=brain, nb_epoch=1000000, batch_size=5,verbose=1)
print "Done"


estimator.fit(X,Y)
prediction = estimator.predict(X)

print Y
print prediction
```

The output is

```python
[3 4 5 6 7]
[0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001]
```

Basically, the prediction is 0.001 while actual value is not.
I've tried with other network configs but I face the same issue.
What must I do/(not do) to get an accurate output??

Comment: Which version of keras do you use? What losses do you get during training?

Comment: It looks like the network is training not at all. Try to change `nb_epoch` to `epochs` if you are using the current version of keras.

Comment: @sietschie tested with `nb_epoch`, too - it is just ignored in new Keras versions and the default value of 10 is used instead. The real issue was data normalization, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a classic mistake made by new practitioners, i.e. *not* normalizing their data before feeding them into a neural network (see the third point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234586/convolutional-neural-network-outputting-equal-probabilities-for-all-labels/48239402#48239402) for the same issue causing similar problems in a classification setting with a convolutional neural network).

(I confess that, in most tutorials I have seen, this crucial point is usually not emphasized strongly enough; and it can be even worse, e.g. in the Tensorflow [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) tutorial, it turns out that the data returned by the Tensorflow-provided utility functions are already normalized in [0, 1], transparently to the user and without any hint provided, hence hiding from the reader a crucial step that will certainly need to be done later, when using own data).

So, you need to normalize both your features *and* your output; keeping your shown `X` and `Y` data:

```python
# Feature Scaling (ignore possible warnings due to conversion of integers to floats)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

sc_Y = StandardScaler()
Y_train = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y)
```

Then, changing your epochs to just 1000 (you definitely don't need 1 million epochs for these data!), and fitting on the scaled data:

```python
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=brain, epochs=1000, batch_size=5,verbose=1)
estimator.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

you will get:

```python
prediction = estimator.predict(X_train)

print(Y_train)
print(prediction)
# [-1.41421356 -0.70710678  0.          0.70710678  1.41421356]
# [-1.01221371 -1.01221371 -0.08764046  0.69051325  1.42577887]
```

Or, scaling your output back to its original range with [`inverse_transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform):

```python
print(Y)
print(sc_Y.inverse_transform(prediction))
# [3 4 5 6 7]
# [ 3.56851363  3.56851363  4.87605762  5.97653294  7.01635551]
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. But I have two doubts:  1) Why is it that every time I run the model, the predicted values keep changing (i.e if it is taking the same training input and has the same algorithm run through it, musn't it give the same output everytime?) ??  2) If I increase the epochs to 10,000, it is giving a completely wrong result where all the predicted values are same. Why is this the case? (given that in linear regression, the more epochs you run, the better it converges..)

Comment: @Thanatos one step (& question) at the time. Since this answer arguably has addressed your reported issue, kindly accept it and open a new one, with the details of your new issue(s), as you have done here. And since you have learned something useful and generally applicable here, upvotes are welcome, too.

Comment: @Thanatos just as an additional argument on opening a new question with the details: it is unclear what you mean by 'run' in (1); if you mean fitting a new model, it is not strange (at least in principle); if you mean running the same fitted model, then that's really strange (but I suspect this is not the case)...

Comment: You can take a look. I've asked this question in another post. Thanks for your help here. It was really valuable as I have less time to get this model going. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476830/kerasregressor-giving-different-output-everytime-i-run-despite-inputs-and-train

Comment: Are you sure the data must be *scaled* only and not *normalised*? The two things are different: scaling produces a distribution with zero expectation value and unit standard deviation, normalisation normalises the vectors to have unit norm (the answer that you link to addresses the latter, not the former).