# KerasRegressor giving different output everytime I run (despite inputs and training set being same)

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Whenever I run the following code, I keep getting different outputs. Please could someone help me out with this? Code:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import numpy as ny

X = ny.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]])
sc_X=StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

Y = ny.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
Y=ny.reshape(Y,(-1,1))
sc_Y=StandardScaler()
Y_train = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y)

N = 5

def brain():
    #Create the brain
    br_model=Sequential()
    br_model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
    br_model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
    br_model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal'))

    #Compile the brain
    br_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
    return br_model


estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=brain, epochs=1000, batch_size=5,verbose=0)

estimator.fit(X_train,Y_train)
prediction = estimator.predict(X_train)


print Y
print sc_Y.inverse_transform(prediction)
```

Basically, I have declared a dataset, am training a neural network to do regression on that and predict the values. Given that everything is already hardcoded into the code, I must be getting the same output everytime I run. However, this is not the case. I request you to help me out.

Comment: Neural networks are initialized randomly, that's why you get a different output every time. Possibly related (not in this case, but useful to keep in mind): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff

Comment: Indeed. In order to get reproducible results, you need to explicitly control the randomness involved - see [How to Get Reproducible Results with Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/)

Comment: Actually - from my experience using these guidelines might result in a very slow and numerically unstable training.