# How to predict a function/table using Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am currently learning keras. My goal is to create a simple model, that predicts values of a function. At first I create two arrays, one for the X-Values and one for the corresponding Y-Values.

```python
# declare and init arrays for training-data
X = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.05)
Y = np.empty(shape=0, dtype=float)

# Calculate Y-Values
for x in X:
    Y = np.append(Y, float(0.05*(15.72807*x - 7.273893*x**2 + 1.4912*x**3 - 0.1384615*x**4 + 0.00474359*x**5)))
```

Then I create and train the model

```python
# model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

and predict the values using the model

```python
# declare and init arrays for prediction
YPredict = np.empty(shape=0, dtype=float)

# Predict Y
YPredict = model.predict(X)

# plot training-data and prediction
plt.plot(X, Y, 'C0')
plt.plot(X, YPredict, 'C1')

# show graph
plt.show()
```

and I get this output (blue is training-data, orange is prediction):

[image: link]

What did I do wrong? I guess it's a fundamental problem with the network-architecture, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed with your network architecture. Specifically, you are using linear activations in all layers: this means that the network can only fit linear functions. You should keep a linear activation in the output layer, but you should use a ReLU activation in the hidden layer:

```python
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

Then, play with the number/size of the hidden layers; I suggest you use a couple more.

Answer (score 2):

On top of the answer provided by BlackBear:

- You should **normalize** both your inputs X and your outputs Y before feeding them into your neural network:

  ```python
  # Feature Scaling (ignore possible warnings due to conversion of integers to floats)
  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

  sc_X = StandardScaler()
  X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

  sc_Y = StandardScaler()
  Y_train = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y)

  # [...]
  model.fit(X_train, Y_train, ...)
  ```

  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458635/getting-very-bad-prediction-with-kerasregressor/48460486#48460486) to see what happens if you don't, in a regression setting very similar to yours. Keep in mind that you should similarly scale any test data using `sc_X`; also, if you need later to scale any `predictions` produced by the model back to the original scale of your Y, you should use

  ```python
  sc_Y.inverse_transform(predictions)
  ```
- Accuracy has no meaning in a regression setting like yours; you should remove `metrics=['accuracy']` from your model compilation (loss itself is enough as a metric here)